# kotlin.collections.EmptyMap cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap

Tags: kotlin, map

Собственно дурацкая ситуация. Есть такая обработка:

```
private fun parse(json: JsonObject): HashMap<String, Probe> {
    return json.keySet()
            .filter { json.get(it).isJsonObject }
            .map { it -> Pair(it, json.getAsJsonObject(it)) }
            .map {
                if (hasInner(it.second))
                    parse(it.second.getAsJsonObject("snapshot_groupSnapshotChildren"))
                else
                    hashMapOf(it.first to probe(it.second))
            }.flatMap { it.toList() }
            .toMap() as HashMap<String, Probe>
}
```

На одной из итераций возвращается пустой `Map`, который, как я понял, в тихую преобразуется в `EmptyMap`, который не умеет каститься в `HashMap`. Как его убедить, что мне нужно вернуть пустой `HashMap`, а не `EmptyMap`?

**UPD** заглянул в исходники `toMap`...

```
public fun <K, V> Iterable<Pair<K, V>>.toMap(): Map<K, V> {
    if (this is Collection) {
        return when (size) {
            0 -> emptyMap()
            1 -> mapOf(if (this is List) this[0] else iterator().next())
            else -> toMap(LinkedHashMap<K, V>(mapCapacity(size)))
        }
    }
    return toMap(LinkedHashMap<K, V>()).optimizeReadOnlyMap()
}
```

PS такие сложности из-за того, что JSON рекурсивный и нужно ключи сохранять

Comment: @zRrr вы абсолютно правы - пропустил этот метод. Оформите ответом пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть метод [`Iterable<Pair<K, V>>.toMap(destination: M)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-map.html), параметром которого является `MutableMap` для заполнения.